# Is this a proper iterator implementation?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am a student trying to work from the ground up with the STL. Right now I'm tasked with implementing iterators. Yes, I know it's reinventing the wheel, but it'll help me to better understand how they work and how they can be applied. Hopefully people can point out if my implementation is too simplistic or missing anything.

```
// ptrdiff_t
#include <cstddef>

template <class Category, class T, class Distance = ptrdiff_t,
          class Pointer = T*, class Reference = T&>
struct iterator 
{
    typedef T         value_type;
    typedef Distance  difference_type;
    typedef Pointer   pointer;
    typedef Reference reference;
    typedef Category  iterator_category; 
};

template <class Iterator> class iterator_traits
{
    typedef typename Iterator::different_type    difference_type;
    typedef typename Iterator::value_type        value_type;
    typedef typename Iterator::pointer           pointer;
    typedef typename Iterator::reference         reference;
    typedef typename Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
};

struct random_access_iterator_tag { };

template <class T> class iterator_traits<T*>
{
    typedef ptrdiff_t                  difference_type;
    typedef T                          value_type;
    typedef T*                         pointer;
    typedef T&                         reference;
    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};

namespace detail
{
    template <class InputIterator>
    void foo(InputIterator& i, random_access_iterator_tag)
    {

    }
}

template <class InputIterator>
void foo(InputIterator& i)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category category;
    detail::foo(i, category);
}
```

Comment: This type of question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You are not actually implementing an iterator. All `std::iterator` (which your `iterator` emulates) does is supply the set of standard typedefs for convenience, but you still have to implement support for the appropriate operations yourself. Also, usually iterators are taken by value.

Comment: +1 for your ardor for study, but it should be in Code Review as Cyber said >o<

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement the standard-library, or shall that be an iterator working with the standard-library? Because for some of those symbols, identity is actually more (or at least as) important as content.